# Rounding differences between Contribution and Bookkeeping reports

Tags: civireport

I am using Drupal 7.66 and CiviCRM 5.10.4. There is a small difference between the total of a Contribution report and a Bookkeeping report using the same filters and therefore intended to produce an identical result. However under certain circumstances there are small rounding errors between the two reports.

Take the following example. A payment of $155.00 is paid via a payment gateway in three monthly instalments. The first instalment is $51.68 and shown in the contribution report correctly (as an aside the next two payments will be $51.66).

However in the Bookkeeping report the first payment is shown as $51.67 which is the rounded up value of $155.00 divided by three which gives $51.66 recurring. In the following month the contribution report will no doubt show the payment to be $51.66 and the Bookkeeping report will display $51.67.

This error also finds its way into the Extended Reports extension. I realise that this is not a big issue but it would be nice if the reports displayed identical totals.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an error. The bookkeeping report is based on records in two different tables than the contribution report. From this report it seems the algorithm for ensuring the series sums to the proper figure used by contributions by having one value different is not properly setting the financial line item values. IIRC there have been some recent changes in this area. Please open an issue at https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/financial/issues and assign it to me.

Comment: I've created the issue but couldn't see how to assign it.

Comment: Do I need to raise an issue with the developers of the Extended Reports extension?

Comment: Thanks @Martin Fuggle. I've opened the right edge of the page to expose the assign widget and completed the assign.